# Custom dialog hasn't divider under the title

Tags: android, android-dialog

At the official documentation there is an article of how to create [custom dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). And there is also a picture of result dialog which have gradient border under it's title.

When I copy this code to run it on my machine and look at the results I get the dialog without
gradient divider between the dialog's title and it's content:

[image]

Is this normal behavior and if it is, tell me how can I add divider by myself through the code, or using styles mechanism?

Comment: what exact details do you need. Is link at the top not enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is a normal behavior for custom dialog. To have the divider below title use something like:

```
    <View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.03dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:background="#404040" />
```

in your custom layout above the layout in which you have the imageview and textview.

Comment: thanks for respond but this isn't similar divider, it hasn't gradient

Comment: you can still create a custom image with gradient and add it to the layout. I can be the only way as per my opinion. As it is just a part of ui.

Comment: I understand it, but one thing I still not understand: where did the original divider go? Maybe you know?

Comment: I have got the same issue while creating custom dialogs in my app. tried to get explanation for this behavior but no luck. I had to add a custom view/image to get that look for the dialog.

Comment: are you testing via emulator or device, if device which model ??