# Activity with Theme.Dialog - how to customise theme to include divider in title bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog, android-theme, titlebar

My issue is exactly the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877455/custom-dialog-hasnt-divider-under-the-title) where my activities with the dialog theme do not display with a divider line underneath the title.

```
<activity android:name="com.identifier.MyActivity"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
</activity>
```

The accepted answer suggests putting a view in the main content of the activity.  However I'd prefer to customise the actual dialog theme rather than have to do this for every activity. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why you say that doesn't work as desired if the contents are scrolled ? Did you tried it ?

Comment: I hadn't realised you could have a view above a scrollview but by adding a linearlayout above it I was able to achieve this. However, I was hoping for way to customise the actual dialog theme itself. I've updated my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this in github https://github.com/inmite/android-styled-dialogs
I hope this is what you need